# Automapper with base class and different configuration options for implementations

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have two classes (MVC view model) which inherits from one abstract base class.

```
abstract class BaseModel { }

class Car : BaseModel 
{
    public string Speed { get; set; }
}

class Camper : BaseModel
{
    public int Beds { get; set; } 
}
```

and want to configure AutoMapper with base class, something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BaseModel, DataDestination>();

var someObj = new DataDastination();
Mapper.Map(instanceOfBaseModel, someObj);
```

Here I get error, because Automapper doesn't have configuration of Car or Camper. Tried configuring Automapper with something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BaseModel, DataDestination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeProp, mapper => mapper.MapFrom( .... ));
```

In MapFrom, I only see properties from base class! How to configure Automapper to use BaseClass, and specific ForMember expression for Car and Camper? For example, if it's a Car, map this property from this, and if it's a Camper, map this property from somewhere else.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is the topic describing [Mapping Inheritance](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html).

The following should work for you:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BaseModel, DataDastination>()
    .Include<Car, DataDastination>()
    .Include<Camper, DataDastination>();//.ForMember(general mapping)
Mapper.CreateMap<Car, DataDastination>();//.ForMember(some specific mapping)
Mapper.CreateMap<Camper, DataDastination>();//.ForMember(some specific mapping)
```

Comment: Not worked for a similar situation explained on [Cannot map from ViewModel to ApplicationUser in AutoMapper 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541588/cannot-map-from-viewmodel-to-applicationuser-in-automapper-5?noredirect=1#comment66397101_39541588). Any idea?

Comment: You saved my day:)

Comment: Shamefully, I don't always reference docs in the first instance. This is a perfect example as to why I should. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Use .IncludeAllDerived()

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BaseModel, DataDestination>().IncludeAllDerived()
Mapper.CreateMap<Car, DataDestination>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Camper, DataDestination>();
```

Comment: ".IncludeAllDerived()" exactly what I was looking for!