# How to minimize code in viewmodel to object conversion?

Tags: c#

I have a objects in my context:

```
abstract public partial class MyAbstractObject
{
    public int Id{set;get;}
    public string Name{set;get;}
}

public partial class MyChildObject: MyAbstractObject
{
    public string Details {set;get;} 
}
```

And i have a view models for ths objects:

```
public class MyAbstractViewModel
{
    public int Id{set;get;}
    public string Name{set;get;}
}

public class MyChildViewModel: MyAbstractViewModel
{
    public string Details {set;get;} 
}
```

Now for convert my view models to objects i use something like:

```
public MyChildObject MakeChildObject(MyChildViewModel vm)
{
  var child = new  MyChildObject();
  child.Id = vm.Id;
  child.Name = vm.Name;
  child.Details= vm.Details;

  return child;
 }
```

My problem in `MyAbstractObject` properties. If i have a several child objects i create a `MakeChildObject` methods for each child object. And all this methods have a same code lines for `MyAbstractObject` properties:

```
  child.Id = vm.Id;
  child.Name = vm.Name;
```

How can i minimize my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider if AutoMapper can be used in your case. It will automatically map objects of different types based on property names. It might save you the time of writing all the mapping code yourself.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

You will then bootstrap the mapper like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyChildViewModel, MyChildObject>();
```

And instead of your method `MakeChildObject` you will use the following:

```
MyChildObject vmMapped = Mapper.Map<MyChildViewModel>(vm);
```

Comment: This sounds spot on for the problem described.

Comment: I don't want to use any libraries. Just want to understad how peoples solving this problem.

Comment: @KliverMax When enough people have solved the same problem someone, somewhere, will develop a library that solves the problem. Then people will stop trying to solve the same problem and use the well tested and robust library.

AutoMapper is open source. You can look at how it does recursive mapping of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code sample to solve your issue.

```
public class MyAbstractViewModel
{
    public int Id{set;get;}
    public string Name{set;get;}

  public void MakeChildObject(MyAbstractViewModel vm, MyAbstractObject child)
  {
    child.Id = vm.Id;
    child.Name = vm.Name;
  }
}

public class MyChildViewModel: MyAbstractViewModel
{
  public string Details {set;get;} 

  public MyChildObject MakeChildObject(MyChildViewModel vm)
  {
    var child = new  MyChildObject();
    this.MakeChildObject(this, child);

    child.Details= vm.Details;

    return child;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look into this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672742/cast-class-into-another-class-or-convert-class-to-another

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at automapper http://automapper.org/

It will automatically map similar named properties. It also includes a feature to map base objects.
See also
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264455/automapper-with-base-class-and-different-configuration-options-for-implementatio)